# How to get video duration from mp4, wmv, flv, mov videos

Tags: c#, .net, video, mp4, duration

Alright. Actually i need mostly the mp4 format. But if it is possible to get for other types as well that would be nice. I just need to read the duration of the file. How can i do that with C# 4.0 ?

So the thing i need is like this video is like : `13 minutes 12 seconds`

I can use 3 third party exes too. Like they save the information about the file to a text file. I can parse that text file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use DirectShow API `MediaDet` object, through DirectShow.NET wrapper library. See [Getting length of video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215185/getting-length-of-video) for code sample, [`get_StreamLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd406887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gets you the duration in seconds. This assumes Windows has MPEG-4 demultiplexer installed (requires third party components with Windows prior to 7, I believe the same applies to another [answer by cezor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10191125/1518265), there are free to redistribute components though).

Comment: Where is this DirectShot API ? Can you also give me the url of this third part ? Or do you mean like k lite mega codec pack ?

Comment: Thanks this line gives the correct duration as seconds :         mediaDet.get_StreamLength(out mediaLength);

Comment: DirectShow is core Windows API, you always have it. Wrapper library http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/ is your C# bridge to DriectShow. The problem with `MP4` files is that you need to have a demultiplexer installed. As it is patented technology, this brings troubles into life - there is no one by default. A good installable/redistributable option is there http://www.gdcl.co.uk/mpeg4/ You only need to figure out how to redist and install it.

Comment: Alright this failed at windows server 2008 r2 but working at my local computer. What do i need to install windows server ? Would k lite mega codec pack work ?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Or, use the link above from GCDL. You need to take DLLs from there and `regsvr32` them inthe target system - this should be sufficient.

Comment: I suppose the cause of error is IMediaDet. It seems like windows server 2008 r2 does not have that ? Please take a look at this error : http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/7446/error2od.png

Comment: Yes, I'd suppose the same. I was under impression it was missing in early builds of Server 2008 and than returned back into place, http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.directx.video/browse_thread/thread/2f508e5944d2111e?q=qedit.dll+windows+server+2008&pli=1

Answer (score 18):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10406221/110776) about P/Invoke for Shell32 reminded me of the [Windows API Code Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) to access common Windows Vista/7/2008/2008R2 APIs.

It was very easy, using the PropertyEdit demo in the included samples, to figure out the Shell32 API to get various media file properties, like duration.

I assume the same prerequisite applies for having the proper demultiplexers installed, but it was quite simple, as it only required adding references to `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.dll` and `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.dll` and the following code:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell;
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.PropertySystem;

using (ShellObject shell = ShellObject.FromParsingName(filePath))
{
    // alternatively: shell.Properties.GetProperty("System.Media.Duration");
    IShellProperty prop = shell.Properties.System.Media.Duration; 
    // Duration will be formatted as 00:44:08
    string duration = prop.FormatForDisplay(PropertyDescriptionFormatOptions.None);
}
```

---

## Other stuff

Some common properties for an MPEG-4/AAC audio media file:

```
System.Audio.Format = {00001610-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}
System.Media.Duration = 00:44:08
System.Audio.EncodingBitrate = ?56kbps
System.Audio.SampleRate = ?32 kHz
System.Audio.SampleSize = ?16 bit
System.Audio.ChannelCount = 2 (stereo)
System.Audio.StreamNumber = 1
System.DRM.IsProtected = No
System.KindText = Music
System.Kind = Music
```

It's easy to iterate through all properties if you're looking for the available metadata:

```
using (ShellPropertyCollection properties = new ShellPropertyCollection(filePath))
{
    foreach (IShellProperty prop in properties)
    {
        string value = (prop.ValueAsObject == null) ? "" : prop.FormatForDisplay(PropertyDescriptionFormatOptions.None);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", prop.CanonicalName, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty neat, but the duration resolution is seconds - I need the fractions, too. Note for anyone trying this, you'll need to add NuGet references to Windows7APICodePack-Core/Shell.

Comment: love it :)  I'm all about the CodePack at this point.  Note the raw value for the property appears to be specifically 10^-7 seconds... I don't know if that much detail is actually provided for all file types, but you can look for it.  The raw value is in property ".ValueAsObject" and it's a ulong you need to cast out of a generic Object.  I'll edit the answer to try to add this.

Answer (score 17):

You could also use windows media player, although it don't support alle file types you requested

```
using WMPLib;

public Double Duration(String file)
    {
        WindowsMediaPlayer wmp = new WindowsMediaPlayerClass();
        IWMPMedia mediainfo = wmp.newMedia(file);
        return mediainfo.duration;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the application will work on windows server 2008. I suppose they don't have windows media player.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Looks like you're right http://stackoverflow.com/a/13929540/188926

Answer (score 5):

IMHO you could use [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) which gives you a lot of information about media files.
There is a CLI for it so you can use it from your code and get info you need.
You can take a look at [this link](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en/Support/SDK).

Comment: Hello. I am not able to add the mediainfodll as a reference. Do you know why ? Here error message : http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/8130/hataow.png

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: you must call application with params and get output, can't use it as a reference inside your solution

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for FFMPEG - https://ffmpeg.org/

there are also some free alternatives that you can read about them in this question - [Using FFmpeg in .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527963/using-ffmpeg-in-net)

> ```
>    FFMpeg.NET
>    FFMpeg-Sharp
>    FFLib.NET
> ```

you can see this link for examples of using FFMPEG and finding the duration - http://jasonjano.wordpress.com/2010/02/09/a-simple-c-wrapper-for-ffmpeg/

```
        public VideoFile GetVideoInfo(string inputPath)
        {
            VideoFile vf = null;
            try
            {
                vf = new VideoFile(inputPath);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            GetVideoInfo(vf);
            return vf;
        }
        public void GetVideoInfo(VideoFile input)
        {
            //set up the parameters for video info
            string Params = string.Format("-i {0}", input.Path);
            string output = RunProcess(Params);
            input.RawInfo = output;

            //get duration
            Regex re = new Regex("[D|d]uration:.((\\d|:|\\.)*)");
            Match m = re.Match(input.RawInfo);

            if (m.Success)
            {
                string duration = m.Groups[1].Value;
                string[] timepieces = duration.Split(new char[] { ':', '.' });
                if (timepieces.Length == 4)
                {
                    input.Duration = new TimeSpan(0, Convert.ToInt16(timepieces[0]), Convert.ToInt16(timepieces[1]), Convert.ToInt16(timepieces[2]), Convert.ToInt16(timepieces[3]));
                }
            }
       }
```

Comment: This is a pay to have application. They provide only trial. This would not work for me :(

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG ffrmpeg is a free software! see: https://ffmpeg.org/legal.html

Answer (score 3):

FFMPEG project has a tool, called ffprobe which can provide you the information you need about your multimedia files and ouput the information in a nicely formated JSON.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16802769/1006863) for an example.

Answer (score 3):

Using Windows Media Player Component also, we can get the duration of the video.
Following code snippet may help you guys :

```
using WMPLib;
// ...
var player = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
var clip = player.newMedia(filePath);
Console.WriteLine(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(clip.duration));
```

> and don't forget to add the reference of **`wmp.dll`** which will be
>   present in **`System32`** folder.

Answer (score 2):

I found the [NReco.VideoInfo library](http://www.nrecosite.com/video_info_net.aspx) to be the best option and far simpler than some of those above. It's a simple as giving the library a file path and it spits out the metadata:

```
var ffProbe = new FFProbe();
var videoInfo = ffProbe.GetMediaInfo(blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
return videoInfo.Duration.TotalMilliseconds;
```

Comment: Just note Commercial Use has a paid license on this one

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and we built a wrapper for ffprobe [Alturos.VideoInfo](https://github.com/AlturosDestinations/Alturos.VideoInfo).
You can use it simply by installing the `nuget` package. Also the [ffprobe](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) binary is required.

```
PM> install-package Alturos.VideoInfo
```

**Example**

```cs
var videoFilePath = "myVideo.mp4";

var videoAnalyer = new VideoAnalyzer("ffprobe.exe");
var analyzeResult = videoAnalyer.GetVideoInfo(videoFilePath);

var duration = analyzeResult.VideoInfo.Format.Duration;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StreamReader errorreader;
string InterviewID = txtToolsInterviewID.Text;

Process ffmpeg = new Process();

ffmpeg.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
ffmpeg.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
ffmpeg.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

ffmpeg.StartInfo.FileName = Server.MapPath("ffmpeg.exe");
ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments = "-i " + Server.MapPath("videos") + "\\226.flv";


ffmpeg.Start();

errorreader = ffmpeg.StandardError;

ffmpeg.WaitForExit();

string result = errorreader.ReadToEnd();

string duration = result.Substring(result.IndexOf("Duration: ") + ("Duration: ").Length, ("00:00:00.00").Length);
```