# Could not load file or assembly 'AxInterop.WMPLib' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect.

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one library AXInterop.WMPLib and it is driving me crazy. this is the error that I receive. I am not using any other dependencies.

Stack Trace:

> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'AxInterop.WMPLib'
>   or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))]
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'AxInterop.WMPLib,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))]
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +34
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +152
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +16    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +28
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'AxInterop.WMPLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is
>   incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))]
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +752
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   +218    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo
>   ai) +130
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +170
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
>   +91    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String
>   preStartInitListPath) +258
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +135
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +516
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   'AxInterop.WMPLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is
>   incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9850940 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +101    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
>   +456

Comment: How are you including this? What kind of reference is it? Have you made sure you have any other assemblies, that the assembly you are using requires? Also, could you include the code where this error occurs?

Answer (score 4):

I assume you develop this application on Windows client (XP, Vista, or 7), and then deploy it to a Windows Server (2008, 2008 R2 and so on)

Windows Media Player is an optional component on Windows Server (different from Windows client such as Windows 7), so you will have to enable it (as part of Desktop Experience role service),

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772567.aspx

After that AxInterop.WMPLib should be able to locate its dependencies (native libraries in Windows Media Player).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error in Windows 10 Pro. The problem was that I was using custom Build Events to compile in another path, and I was missing to add the libraries into the project compilation folder.

So, be sure to add the **AxInterop.WMPLib.dll** and **Interop.WMPLib.dll** into the project folder.