# VS: WMPLib.dll loading error

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Sorry for ask this basic question. I am a newbie in VS ann C#.

I have read many artcicles and books about VS and C#, but I have no practice.

I downloaded a C# solution from github and I am trying build it with C# with Visual Studio 2015.

When I try to build with Debug Option all works well and no errors.

But, if I use the Release option I get:
"Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\XXX\AxInterop.WMPLib.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515 (E_INVALIDARG))]"

Some help, please.

Luiz

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this post?  [Could not load file or assembly 'AxInterop.WMPLib' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929021/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-axinterop-wmplib-or-one-of-its-dependencies-t)

Sounds like some Operating systems may have this issue.

Comment: I don´t think that my problem is the same, because all build ok in debug mode. My problem  happens with Release mode.