# Get uploaded video duration in mvc

Tags: c#, video, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How can we get the duration of uploaded video in mvc controller ? When I have uploaded video it only give `content-type`,`content-length` etc kind of details but not the duration of the video.

So how can we get the duration of the video in mvc ?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get video duration from mp4, wmv, flv, mov videos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190906/how-to-get-video-duration-from-mp4-wmv-flv-mov-videos)

Comment: For the most part, "meta information" of different file types is natively not available through .NET and you'll often have to rely on a third-party library. I tried to recently write something to re-name a ton of music files of mine using the meta data for aritst, album, track etc. but there is no .NET support for that either. See the "Possible Duplicate" link I tagged this as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yuo can use [FFMPEG Wrapper](https://github.com/lecode-official/ffmpeg-dotnet) for .NET Core to extract any information about uploaded video but be careful because it's still on beta (https://github.com/lecode-official/ffmpeg-dotnet/blob/master/Source/FFmpegDotNet.Interop/Formats/AVDurationEstimationMethod.cs)

Comment: How can i install this in .net core ?

Comment: You can read on `README.MD` section `Using the Project`. Install scripts  are already in bash but you can use it by Windows Subsystem for Linux directly without rewriting to Powershell

Comment: Exactly ! I am running the bash commands on win-7, but that is giving the error

Comment: Windows Subsystem for Linux is not only Windows 10 feature? Can you past here errors?

Comment: This package seems to be dead, 2 years ago since the last commit

Answer (score 2):

You can use this nuget package:

```
Install-Package Xabe.FFMpeg
```

I'm trying to make easy to use, cross-platform FFmpeg wrapper.

You can find more information about this at [Xabe.FFmpeg](https://xabe.net/product/xabe_ffmpeg/)

```
IMediaInfo mediaInfo = await MediaInfo.Get("videofile.mkv");
var videoDuration = mediaInfo.VideoStreams.First().Duration;
```

More info about getting duration of video file in
[documentation](https://xabe.net/product/xabe_ffmpeg/#documentation)

Answer (score 0):

just for those who doesn't know how to do it

first add package

```
<PackageReference Include="Xabe.FFMpeg" Version="3.1.0" />
```

then

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Load().Wait();

        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }


 public static async Task Load()
    {
        //Set directory where app should look for FFmpeg 
        FFmpeg.ExecutablesPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "FFmpeg");
        //Get latest version of FFmpeg. It's great idea if you don't know if you had installed FFmpeg.
        await FFmpeg.GetLatestVersion();
    }
```

and usage

```
   IMediaInfo mediaInfo = await MediaInfo.Get(@"C:\Users\username\source\repos\MyWebApp\uploads\videos\file1.mp4");
        var videoDuration = mediaInfo.VideoStreams.First().Duration;
```

Comment: I would mention which Nuget package I used to write this code

Answer (score 0):

First, I try  **FFMPEG Wrapper** but it gets an error after found an easy solution.

You can use this nugget package:

```
 Install-Package Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Shell -Version 1.1.0
```

In your project add two namespaces.

> using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell; 
>       using.Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.PropertySystem;

```
ShellFile so = ShellFile.FromFilePath(your file path);
double nanoseconds;
double.TryParse(so.Properties.System.Media.Duration.Value.ToString(),
out nanoseconds);

if (nanoseconds > 0)
{
     double seconds = Convert100NanosecondsToMilliseconds(nanoseconds) / 1000;
     int ttl_seconds = Convert.ToInt32(seconds);
     TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ttl_seconds);
} 

public static double Convert100NanosecondsToMilliseconds(double nanoseconds)
{           
        return nanoseconds * 0.0001;
}
```

Here i store seconds in **TimeSpan** so its directly give hours:minutes:seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Using Windows Media Player Component also, we can get the duration of the video.
Following code snippet may help you guys :

```
using WMPLib;
// ...
var player = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
var clip = player.newMedia(filePath);
Console.WriteLine(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(clip.duration));
```

> and don't forget to add the reference of **`wmp.dll`** which will be
>   present in **`System32`** folder.