# Mvc Asp.Net On video upload read duration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, video

Is there a way to read video duration on video upload in MVC Asp.Net

In controller I access uploaded file as `HttpPostedFileBase`

It provides only length in bytes but I need a way to get video duration in seconds.

[image]
[image]

Is there way to get this, some good library for this available as NuGet Package or anything else.

Comment: [How to get video duration from mp4, wmv, flv, mov videos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190906/how-to-get-video-duration-from-mp4-wmv-flv-mov-videos)