# How to get video length / duration programatically in C# (Universal windows apps)?

Tags: c#, video, win-universal-app, duration

I've searched about this for a while, and most answers seem to suggest using the directshow library, which I've tried, but it didn't work. My program currently works on selecting a video file using the FileOpenPicker, then checks its length and uploads it to the cloud if it's below a certain length. Please keep in mind that this needs to work for Universal Windows Apps.

Comment: You might want to tell us will file formats you're supporting. Getting length of a DVD is different than of an AVI file for example.

Comment: I guess I'd like to support as many formats as possible down the road, but for now I'm using MP4 files only

Answer (score 0):

You can use DirectShow API `MediaDet` object, through DirectShow.NET wrapper library. See [Getting length of video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215185/getting-length-of-video) for code sample, [`get_StreamLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd406887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gets you the duration in seconds. This assumes Windows has MPEG-4 demultiplexer installed (requires third party components with Windows prior to 7, I believe the same applies to another [answer by cezor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10191125/1518265), there are free to redistribute components though).You can use DirectShow API `MediaDet` object, through DirectShow.NET wrapper library. See [Getting length of video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215185/getting-length-of-video) for code sample, [`get_StreamLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd406887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gets you the duration in seconds. This assumes Windows has MPEG-4 demultiplexer installed (requires third party components with Windows prior to 7, I believe the same applies to another [answer by cezor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10191125/1518265), there are free to redistribute components though).

Comment: I did try the method provided in the first link of your answer prior to posting this question, but it didn't work. It threw an exception and gave me a "class not registered" error. That's why I was hoping to find a solution that'd work when developing for windows universal apps