# Get the duration of video in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, video, duration

I needed the duration of video from physical path.

The code that I have tried is:

```
using WMPLib;
WindowsMediaPlayer wmp = new WindowsMediaPlayerClass();
IWMPMedia mediaInfo = wmp.newMedia(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/test.mp4"));
double duration = mediaInfo.duration;
```

But I am getting following error:

> The type 'WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayerClass' has no constructors defined
>     Interop type 'WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayerClass' cannot be embedded.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215185/getting-length-of-video